# Understanding MVVM and ObjectDetailViewModel in Udemy Course

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

I've been doing a course for Xamarin and I am at the MVVM portion where all the xaml.cs code is moved to  ViewModels.

This is the course (lecture #104, 105, 106): [url]https://www.udemy.com/course/complete-xamarin-developer-course-ios-and-android[/url]

So far I've been able to understand the concept of MVVM, however, the course seems to do a few things incorrectly (as I believe) and some of the code in previous lectures isn't in the new lectures (we'll leave that annoyance alone for now), moving forward, I am not sure how to code it correctly.  I also understand that I am presenting a simple use case at the moment so let's think that Post is a huge object that shouldn't be re-created over and over.

For example, I have a `PostDetailPage.xaml(.cs)`, in the xaml, I currently have the following (note that most of the Mode=TwoWay might not be used properly):

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Margin="10">
        <Entry x:Name="experienceEntry" 
               Text="{Binding Experience, Mode=TwoWay}"
               Margin="-5"></Entry>
        <label x:name="venuename"
               text="{binding post.venuename, mode=onetime}"
               fontattributes="bold"/>
        <label x:name="categoryname"
               text="{binding post.categoryname, mode=onetime}"/>
        <label x:name="address"
               text="{binding post.address, mode=onetime}"/>
        <label x:name="coordinatelabel"
               text="{binding coordinates, mode=onetime}"/>
        <label x:name="distance"
               text="{binding post.distance, mode=onetime, stringformat='{0:0}'}"/>

        <Button Text="Update"
                x:Name="updateButton"
                Command="{Binding UpdatePostCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Post}" />

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code behind is the following:

```
public partial class PostDetailPage : ContentPage
{
    PostDetailViewModel viewModel;

    public PostDetailPage(Post selectedPost)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new PostDetailViewModel(selectedPost);
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Then I have an incomplete PostDetailViewModel:

```
public class PostDetailViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public UpdatePostCommand UpdatePostCommand { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public PostDetailViewModel(Post post)
    {
        UpdatePostCommand = new UpdatePostCommand(this);
        SelectedPost = post;
    }

    //Can this become another ViewModel or ?
    private Post selectedPost;
    public Post SelectedPost
    {
        get { return selectedPost; }
        set 
        {
            selectedPost = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Post");
        }
    }

    private string experience;
    public string Experience
    {
        get { return experience; }
        set
        {
            experience = value;
            UpdatePostObject();
            OnPropertyChanged("Experience");
        }
    }

    private void UpdatePostObject() {
        Post = new Post() {
            Experience = experience,

            //many more properties are needed here
            //seems like if the solution was to grow,
            //this would become unmanagable or something

        }
    }

    private void UpdatePostObject()
    {
        //This is used to Trigger the change on Post
        //I don't think this is the best way (hence my question(s))
        SelectedPost = new Post()
        {
            Experience = experience
        };
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public async void Update()
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HistoryPage());
    }
}
```

From the course, the instructor recommends that when `Experience` is changed (or any other property related to `Post`), that we re-create the `Post` object again and again to trigger `CanExecute` and associated `Execute`.  This seems incorrect to have to re-create the `Post` object again and again after each change, so would updating only what is needed be best?

So, what I am asking (or learning about) is...

1. Should I implement a generic `PostViewModel` that is updaded when `Experience` has changed and somehow attach the `ICommand` to it, if so, how would something like that look like?  Of course, if this is not correct, please point me in the right direction if possible.
2. Is there some type of `OnObjectChanged` like method that could be used?  I know of the `ObservableCollection` when dealing with collections.

Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide.

Thank you
Derek

Answer (score 0):

First of all I cannot open your url, this course is missing.

> Should I implement a generic PostViewModel that is updaded when Experience has changed and somehow attach the ICommand to it, if so, how would something like that look like? Of course, if this is not correct, please point me in the right direction if possible.

For the `UpdatePostObject` method, you do not need to new a `Post` object, If you want to set the new value for the `selectedPost` object, just set it like following code directly,

```
   private void UpdatePostObject()
        {
            selectedPost.Experience = experience;
            selectedPost.address= "new Adree";



            selectedPost.categoryname = "new CateGoryName";
            selectedPost.distance = "41";
            selectedPost.venuename = "new venu";

                //many more properties are needed here
                //seems like if the solution was to grow,
                //this would become unmanagable or something

           // };
        }
```

If you want to achieve the click command, you just declear the `public ICommand UpdatePostCommand { get; set; }` in `PostDetailViewModel`. Then achieve it in your `PostDetailViewModel`'s constructor. Here is my all code about `PostDetailViewModel`

```
   public class PostDetailViewModel 
    {
        //: INotifyPropertyChanged
        public ICommand UpdatePostCommand { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public PostDetailViewModel(Post post)
        {
            UpdatePostCommand = new Command<Post>((key) => {


                key.categoryname = "Command categoryname";
                key.distance = "31";
                key.address = "Command address";
                key.venuename = "Command  venuename";
                key.Experience = "Command Experience";

            });






            SelectedPost = post;
        }

        //Can this become another ViewModel or ?
        private Post selectedPost;
        public Post SelectedPost
        {
            get { return selectedPost; }
            set
            {
                selectedPost = value;
             //   OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPost");
            }
        }

        private string experience;
        public string Experience
        {
            get { return experience; }
            set
            {
                experience = value;
                UpdatePostObject();
              //  OnPropertyChanged("Experience");
            }
        }

        private void UpdatePostObject()
        {
            selectedPost.Experience = experience;
            selectedPost.address= "new Adree";



            selectedPost.categoryname = "new CateGoryName";
            selectedPost.distance = "41";
            selectedPost.venuename = "new venu";

                //many more properties are needed here
                //seems like if the solution was to grow,
                //this would become unmanagable or something

           // };
        }

        //private void UpdatePostObject()
        //{
        //    //This is used to Trigger the change on Post
        //    //I don't think this is the best way (hence my question(s))
        //    SelectedPost = new Post()
        //    {
        //        Experience = experience
        //    };
        //}

        //public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        //protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        //{
        //    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        //}
        public async void Update()
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HistoryPage());
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to achieve the attribute change at the running time, you should achieve the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for all of your attribute in your `POST` model.

```
   public class Post:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
     //   public string _venuename { get; set; }
      //  public string categoryname { get; set; }
        string _categoryname;
        public string categoryname
        {
            set
            {
                if (_categoryname != value)
                {
                    _categoryname = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("categoryname");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return _categoryname;
            }
        }

        //public string address { get; set; }


        string _address;
        public string address
        {
            set
            {
                if (_address != value)
                {
                    _address = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("address");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return _address;
            }
        }


       // public string Experience { get; set; }

        string _experience;
        public string Experience
        {
            set
            {
                if (_experience != value)
                {
                    _experience = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Experience");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return _experience;
            }
        }

      //  public string distance { get; set; }

        string _distance;
        public string distance
        {
            set
            {
                if (_distance != value)
                {
                    _distance = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("distance");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return _distance;
            }
        }

        string _venuename;
        public string venuename
        {
            set
            {
                if (_venuename != value)
                {
                    _venuename = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("venuename");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return _venuename;
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And you layout have some errors, I change of them.

```
   <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Margin="10">
            <Entry x:Name="experienceEntry" 
               Text="{Binding Experience, Mode=TwoWay}"
               Margin="-5">

            </Entry>

            <Label x:Name="venuename"
               Text="{Binding SelectedPost.venuename, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
              />
            <Label x:Name="categoryname"
               Text="{Binding SelectedPost.categoryname, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label x:Name="address"
               Text="{Binding SelectedPost.address, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label x:Name="coordinatelabel"
               Text="{Binding SelectedPost.coordinates, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label x:Name="distance"
               Text="{Binding SelectedPost.distance, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{0:0}'}"/>

            <Button Text="Update"
                x:Name="updateButton"
                Command="{Binding UpdatePostCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedPost}" />

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Here is my layout background code.

```
   public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Post selectedPost=new Post() { 
                address= "address", 
                categoryname= "categoryname", 
                distance= "21", 

                venuename= "venuename" };
            PostDetailViewModel viewModel = new PostDetailViewModel(selectedPost);
            BindingContext = viewModel;
        }
    }
```

> Is there some type of OnObjectChanged like method that could be used? I know of the ObservableCollection when dealing with collections.

In your `PostDetailViewModel` it is no need to achieve that.  If you want to use `ObservableCollection` to add `Post` , it achieve the `INotifyPropertyChanged`, If you `Post` items will increate or decrease, it will change automatically, But if value of `Post` will be changed, it will not change, you have to achieve the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `Post` model.

Here is my running GIF.Normally, it have some default value, if I enter the value in the Entry, this value of post will be changed, if I click the `Button`, the value of post will be changed to another value

[image]

Here is a helpful article about it, you can refer to it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: Are there any update for this issue? If this answer is helpful, please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) it will help others who have similar issue